# Fastest way to get the first n elements of a List into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, performance

What is the fastest way to get the first n elements of a list stored in an array?

Considering this as the scenario:

```
int n = 10;
ArrayList<String> in = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < (n+10); i++)
  in.add("foobar");
```

**Option 1:**

```
String[] out = new String[n];
for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    out[i]=in.get(i);
```

**Option 2:**

```
String[] out = (String[]) (in.subList(0, n)).toArray();
```

**Option 3:**
Is there a faster way? Maybe with Java8-streams?

Comment: I expect it varies by platform and JVM, you should try benchmarking it yourself.

Comment: Why should it depent on the jvm? How could I calculate the Complexity?

Comment: The complexity is easy. It's `O(n)`. The actual performance varies.

Comment: both are basically doing the same thing, if you look at the source for `subList` and `toArray`

Comment: Just to say it: if n isn't at least in the millions, the complexity is irrelevant to the time taken. And actually, if this code isn't used thousand of times at the least, its performance is irrelevant to whatever app you're developing. So, most probably you should think more about readability than performance

Comment: Now, if you're actually in a case where performance is crititcal (I mean billions of items and calls), use option 1: the code is simpler so the JIT should work better. But always profile performance of your whole code before trying to improve it: time is usually mostly consumed on network communication, IO, or in places we don't think of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Option 1 Faster Than Option 2

Because Option 2 creates a new `List` reference, and then creates an `n` element array from the `List` (option 1 perfectly sizes the output array). However, first you need to fix the off by one bug. Use `<` (not `<=`). Like,

```
String[] out = new String[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    out[i] = in.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly enough, `subList` does not copy. It is a view on the existing list.

Comment: @njzk2 Unless that view is a no-op, I'd expect option 1 to be faster anyway.

Comment: creating the view is basically creating an object with a few variables. No loop, no copy, not much, really.

Comment: The `toArray` is a bit more involved.

Comment: and also safer, with actual bound checks (like if `n >= in.size()`, or if someone changes the List in the mean time).

Answer (score 150):

Assumption:

list - List`<String>`

Using Java 8 Streams,

- to get first N elements from a list into a list,

  `List<String> firstNElementsList = list.stream().limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList());`
- to get first N elements from a list into an Array,

  `String[] firstNElementsArray = list.stream().limit(n).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[n]);`

Comment: Why should this be faster than #1?

Comment: If I only have 1 element, and I use the above streaming way, I get 1 element and null

Comment: @jagamot If N is less than the array size use `toArray(String[]::new)` instead.

Comment: `.limit(n).toList()` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

It mostly depends on how big `n` is.

If `n==0`, nothing beats option#1 :)

If n is very large, `toArray(new String[n])` is faster.

Comment: the range n is about 1-5, where as the size of the `in`-List is about double the size

Comment: very sure option#1 then.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 3**

Iterators are faster than using the `get` operation, since the `get` operation has to start from the beginning if it has to do some traversal. It probably wouldn't make a difference in an ArrayList, but other data structures could see a noticeable speed difference. This is also compatible with things that aren't lists, like sets.

```
String[] out = new String[n];
Iterator<String> iterator = in.iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < n && iterator.hasNext(); i++)
    out[i] = iterator.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.take(n)` operator on your list

Comment: Can you please explain in detail which method you mean? In the [List interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) there is no method called like this.

Comment: This can be a comment

Comment: @vanje looks like this extension is only available on kotlin, sorry for confusing. However I would like this answer to be here because I being a kotlin user ended up here in search of this function. So other kotlin users can come to this topic and get the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayList.stream().limit(n).toArray();

n = maxSize in length
```

This will help you to get the max size of the Array that you require.

Comment: Why is this faster than the other options?

Answer (score -6):

Use:
Arrays.copyOf(yourArray,n);